# Excel formula for ratios to reach a total

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet which allows the user to enter a budget e.g. "£100,000".

Whatever budget figure is entered by user, I want my spreadsheet to calculate a number of days of 3 different labour types that the budget will cover: bricklayer; electrician; or plumber.

Each labour type has a different day rate:

- Bricklayer @ £100 per day
- Electrician @ £250 per day
- Plumber @ £250 per day

The calculation should maintain a consistent ratio of each labour type as follows:

- Bricklayer: 0.5
- Electrician: 0.25
- Plumber: 0.25

So for example, if the user enters a budget of £100,000, I want the spreadsheet to automatically calculate:

- Bricklayer: 285.714 days
- Electrician: 142.857 days
- Plumber: 142.857 days

I need help working out the correct formula to use to calculate the correctly weighted number of days based on the budget.

Comment: This is actually a very simple maths problem rather than an Excel problem. You have also got the wrong solution for a budget of 100,000. The correct solution is Bricklayer:285.714 days, the others 142.857 days. The formula is: #BricklayerDays = budget/350 and #OthersDays = #BrickLayerDays/2.

Comment: You don't have enough detail to calculate this, with or without Excel.  You don't pay a ratio, you pay workers.  Does everyone work in whole day increments?  If so, your ratios suggest some multiple of 2 bricklayers, 1 electrician, + 1 plumber.  The number of budget days depends on the multiple.  If the multiple is 1, the number of days is 142.857.  But no job works like this, so it sounds like a puzzle or school exercise.  In any event, this isn't an excel problem, at least as presented, so not really on-topic (and certainly not clear enough to answer).

Comment: Thanks @robinCTS! Your formula is what I was looking for.

@fixer1234: It's not a puzzle or a school exercise. I am building a 'job cost estimator' spreadsheet for my work for sales people to use to calculate estimates.

Comment: @fixer1234 What is clear to one person is like mud to another ;-) I totally agree with you that it's completely off-topic (it's a maths problem), but completely disagree that it's not clear ***enough***, or has *enough* details, to answer. Is it clear? No. Are the details confusing? Yes - some were incorrect, in fact.

Comment: Do you want man-days or budget days?  You've changed the question to show man-days, but the description refers to budget days (which would be 142.857 for the combination).  What is the objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a formula which enables you to enter full cost, and also adjust parameters.

Just create the sheet as below then enter formula in G2 and fill down.

`=$E$2/SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$4,$C$2:$C$4)*C2`

[image]

Comment: OK. This answer now makes the question basically ***on***-topic :-P